# Get XML attribute value based on parent element and value

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'd like to assign the values of the attributes in the xml below to variables. But I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for referring to the attribute I want. For instance, how would I refer to the attribute called "qatest" that is

- a child element of "asr"
- has the value of "en-US"

  ```
  <asr>
      <item qatest="http://app05-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz92.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">en-US</item>
      <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">en-GB</item>
      <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">fr-FR</item>
      <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">it-IT</item>
      <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">de-DE</item>
      <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status"  qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">pt-BR</item>
      <item qatest=http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status"" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ru-RU</item>
      <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">zh-CN</item>
      <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ja-JP</item>
      <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ko-KR</item>
  </asr>

  <lmtt>
      <item qatest="http://app14-test.qa.example.com:8080/lmtt/status" qadmz="http://qadmz94.dmz.example.com:8080/lmtt/status">all</item>
  </lmtt>
  ```

I have found this code so far, but it isn't specific enough to know what parent element and what value the attribute are related to

```
attrValue = xml.GetAttrValue("qatest")
```

I struggle with XML terminology still, so please ask if I've used an incorrect term.

Comment: You can extract an attribute value using XmlNode, for a example, "foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) { ... }" then "string _qatest = node.Attributes["qatest"].Value;" (c# version which can be converted to vb.net).

Comment: Do you need just one xmlnode, or are you trying to loop through them? Do you already know how to load the xml doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a single value result (if no duplicates exist) then try the following [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) approach:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim XDocument1 As XDocument =
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <Data>
            <asr>
                <item qatest="http://app05-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz92.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">en-US</item>
                <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">en-GB</item>
                <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">fr-FR</item>
                <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">it-IT</item>
                <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">de-DE</item>
                <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">pt-BR</item>
                <item qatest="http://app10-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz97.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ru-RU</item>
                <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">zh-CN</item>
                <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ja-JP</item>
                <item qatest="http://app12-test.qa.example.com:8080/asr/status" qadmz="http://qadmz98.dmz.example.com:8080/asr/status">ko-KR</item>
            </asr>
            <lmtt>
                <item qatest="http://app14-test.qa.example.com:8080/lmtt/status" qadmz="http://qadmz94.dmz.example.com:8080/lmtt/status">all</item>
            </lmtt>
        </Data>

    Dim ElementName1 As String = "asr"
    Dim ElementValue1 As String = "en-US"
    Dim AttributeName1 As String = "qatest"
    Dim AttributeValue1 As String = ""

    Dim XElement1 As XElement = (From X1 In XDocument1.Descendants Where X1.Name = ElementName1)(0)

    If Not XElement1 Is Nothing Then
        Dim XElement2 As XElement = (From X2 In XElement1.Elements Where X2.Value = ElementValue1)(0)

        If Not XElement2 Is Nothing AndAlso Not XElement2.Attribute(AttributeName1) Is Nothing Then
            AttributeValue1 = XElement2.Attribute(AttributeName1).Value
        End If
    End If

    If AttributeValue1.Length > 0 Then
        MsgBox(AttributeValue1)
    Else
        MsgBox("No match found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works for me. I just changed to load my xml from file with "Dim XDocument1 As XDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath & "test.xml")". Thanks!

Comment: What are X1 and X2 referring to?

Comment: The `X1` represent an [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337483%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection of `XDocument1`. When we set `X1.Name = ElementName1` in the [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384663.aspx) clause, that filters the specific `XElement` name which satisfies the equation. After that if a match will been found, the `X2` will filter the `XElement1`'s Elements collection so that the specific Element Value is found.

Answer (score 0):

This works by loading the xml doc, then selecting a particular node that matches some conditions. `test[text()='some text'` selects the node based on a text value and `@` signals to select the attribute of the selected node. You can use other methods, such as selecting a list of nodes matching a condition, then loop through them. Let me know if you want to see that kind of code.

```
Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument()
doc.Load("c:/yourfile.XML")

Dim nValue = "en-US"
Dim xNodeAttr As Xml.XmlAttribute = doc.SelectSingleNode("/asr/item[text()='" & nValue & "' and //@qatest]")
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the doc.Load statement. I'd like to load the file "text.xml", and I used "
    Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(filePath & "test.xml"), but I get message "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: I edited my code--had my usage in it. Sounds like your file isn't loading. what is your file path?